# Alsa library has different version of read and driver interaction functions why?

Tags: linux-kernel, alsa, libalsa

I was going through alsa library code, I wanted to know read function that is being used. However I see there are more than one version of read functions. 
i.e

```
.readi = snd_pcm_hw_readi
.readi = snd_pcm_ioplug_readi
.readi = snd_pcm_mmap_readi
.readi = snd_pcm_dshare_readi
.readi = snd_pcm_plugin_readi
```

I am not sure how does alsa library choose which function to use ?

what params make it choose different API's (like swparams ,hwparams)

Comment: Those are from different plugins.

Comment: alsa.conf is the only file decides what plugins we use ?

Comment: You give a device name to `snd_pcm_open()`, and that name is looked up in the configuration files.

Comment: one varitation that I saw was "snd_pcm_plugin_fast_ops" that was decided based on hw_params and requested params. in "snd_pcm_plug_insert_plugins" function